# Keep only the last duplicate line

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have this data, how to remove the first duplicate ($1$2$3) using awk

```
785016 AGTCGCGTCCGT 142
785031 CGGCGTCGACTA 705
785031 CGGCGTCGACTA 705 CACTCCCCTGGAG
848841 GCTCAGTCAAAC 1595
848841 GCTCAGTCAAAC 1595    matched
848847 CAAATCGAGATC 1672
880844 TGCCGACGACAT 520
880844 TGCCGACGACAT 520 GTGTTCCGATCAG
880851 GACGACAACGTC 582
```

the expected output is

```
785016 AGTCGCGTCCGT 142
785031 CGGCGTCGACTA 705 CACTCCCCTGGAG
848841 GCTCAGTCAAAC 1595    matched
848847 CAAATCGAGATC 1672
880844 TGCCGACGACAT 520 GTGTTCCGATCAG
880851 GACGACAACGTC 582
```

Comment: Your example is wrong, or the title is incorrect. The example shows removing 3 duplicates, not the first one – 3 lines of the input are missing in the output.

Comment: Additionally, the missing lines are originals, not duplicates – duplicating lines are kept (e.g. line 3), but _original_ ones are missing (resp. 2).

Comment: In your question, add what you have tried to do yourself to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac file | awk '!a[$1,$2,$3]++' | tac
```

Output:

```
785016 AGTCGCGTCCGT 142
785031 CGGCGTCGACTA 705 CACTCCCCTGGAG
848841 GCTCAGTCAAAC 1595    matched
848847 CAAATCGAGATC 1672
880844 TGCCGACGACAT 520 GTGTTCCGATCAG
880851 GACGACAACGTC 582
```

See: `man tac`

Comment: In general you can't make a unique key by directly concatenating strings since `a bc` => `abc` and `ab c` => `abc`. You'll probably get away with it given the OPs sample input but it'd be much more robust and idiomatic to use `a[$1,$2,$3]` than `a[$1$2$3]` and there's no down side to doing that.